Is there any way to return Oracle SQL JSON without the wrapping {}
So for example
    SELECT json_object ('hist' VALUE NULL FORMAT JSON)
  FROM DUAL;

returns
{"hist":null}

I would like it to return
"hist":null

I do a great deal of JSON generation using many different sources that are combined in a single document. So the extra wrapper is causing issues.
Thanks
Larry

It's no longer valid JSON without the braces

Not sure why you'd do that, but if you did want to, simply strip them off:
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(json_object ('hist' VALUE NULL FORMAT JSON),'{'),'}')
  FROM dual

Or if you want only the outermost removed if it should start with {{ or end with }}:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(json_object ('hist' VALUE NULL FORMAT JSON),'{(.*)}','\1')
  FROM dual

And a half dozen other ways of basic string manipulation.
